# Хранение локальных переменных в c#

Tags: c#, память

Пытаюсь разобраться с хранением данных в c#.
Вот например, есть, когда IL-оператор Stloc берет верхнее значение стека и помещает его в локальную переменную, где эта сама переменная хранится?
Например,

```
static void Main()
{
    {
        int x = 5;
    }
}
```

В Il-нотации это

```
.method private hidebysig static void Main() cil managed
{
    .entrypoint
    .maxstack 1
    .locals init (
        [0] int32 num)
    L_0000: nop 
    L_0001: nop 
    L_0002: ldc.i4.5 
    L_0003: stloc.0 <---В какую область памяти упадет значение из стека?
    L_0004: nop 
    L_0005: ret 
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

В Майкрософтовской CLR локальные переменные хранятся обычно* в стеке, в фрейме, выделенном для текущей функции. Стек — [деталь имплементации](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail-part-one/) текущего JIT-компилятора, его нет на уровне IL-кода (и может в принципе не быть в других имплементациях CLR).

IL-код представляет собой стековую машину, стек которой для Microsoft CLR лишь описательная конструкция, и преобразуется в «обычный» регистровый код при JIT-компиляции. IL-стек не имеет ничего общего со стеком, с которым работает JIT-компилятор, и является лишь формальным компонентом.

---

*Исключения:

- Переменная может попасть в замыкание, тогда она *поднимается* до поля созданного класса
- Переменная может быть в генераторе (yield-функции) или async-функции, тогда она поднимается до поля созданной для функции стейт-машины.
- Переменная может быть уничтожена оптимизатором на этапе компиляции (или JIT-компиляции), тогда её вообще нигде нет.

Comment: "_аллоцированном_"? :) ладно еще имплементация в ходу вроде, но аллоцированный :)

Comment: @teran: А как правильно сказать?

Comment: дак выделенный по русски вроде, или нет? :) память то выделяете под объект вроде, а не аллоцируете.

Comment: @teran: И правда! Поменял, спасибо.